# Button в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css, mobile

Доброе время суток! Есть кнопка для входа, на ПК отображается правильно, но стоит зайти через телефон, кнопка становится другая, а сам сайт отображается правильно.
В css правило для кнопки, на всякий случай выложу: 

`input[type="button"] {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 116px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6383A8;
}`

Помогите, как вернуть прежний вид?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно на телефоне по-другому? Какая ОС на телефоне?

Comment: IOS, Кнопка по другому все остальное нормально, проверял в safari и в yandex browser одно и то же

Comment: Но что именно по-другому, уточните: шрифт, высота, ширина, цвет...?

Comment: Полностью вся кнопка, она другого цвета, не круглая

Comment: @Владислав, возможно у вас bootstrap? скиньте весь код, пожалуйста(или фиддл), также попробуйте через другой браузер мобильного(хром, опера, т.д.)

Comment: Вот стиль кнопки:

`input[type="button"].vk_btn {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 116px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6383A8;
}`  


Вот html:
`<input class="vk_btn" onClick="window.open('http://vk.com')" type="button" name="vk" value="Вконтакте">`

Скинул не совсем тот, но там тоже самое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте к стилю кнопки свойства:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance:none;
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, а можно как то закругление убрать кнопок?

Comment: Попробуйте `-webkit-border-radius:0;-moz-border-radius:0;` Я думал это только Андрогуманоиды искажают appearance. Оказывается "яблоки" тоже)

Comment: Блин спасибо тебе большое, последний вопрос. Не подскажешь как можно вернуть длину input т.к она изменилась, стала меньше?

Comment: попробуйте установить инпуту свойство `display: block;`, сейчас похоже на то, что он инлайновый по умолчанию, для инлайновых элементов ширина не задаётся

Comment: Уже прописан, не решает эту проблему( Может есть другие варианты?